# JavaFX Drawing Shapes via Mouse

Tags: javafx, drawing

Is there any easy way to draw a some shape by moving mouse?

To be more specific, I'm doing a screenshot program, so I want to select display the area somehow. 
I see it like holding mouse key on point A and moving it to point B in realtime, drawing the rectangle between point A and current point.

Sorry for bad language, English is not my native.

Comment: There is nothing built in: you just have to implement this directly with mouse handlers. (`setOnMousePressed(...)`, `setOnMouseDragged(...)`, `setOnMouseReleased(...)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using a Scene object called scene in this case. This or something like it should probably do what you want it, perhaps you have to switch between `dragBox.setTranslate` and `dragBox.setWidth` / `.setHeight` in the cases where you're dragging up or left instead of down and right.

```
Rectangle dragBox = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
dragBox.setVisible(false);
scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        if(mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED){
            dragBox.setVisible(true);
            dragBox.setTranslateX(mouseEvent.getX());
            dragBox.setTranslateY(mouseEvent.getY());
        }
        if(mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED && dragBox.isVisible()){
            dragBox.setWidth(mouseEvent.getX() - dragBox.getTranslateX());
            dragBox.setHeight(mouseEvent.getY() - dragBox.getTranslateY());
        }
        if(mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED)
            dragBox.setVisible(false);
    }
});
```

You also have to make sure to add the dragBox to the Pane that is being showed in the scene, or else the dragBox won't be visible at all.

Comment: It works not like expected :c But I see the logic how you do it. Thanks for help :)

Comment: That's good, let me know if you discover what mistakes I may have done, I guess it's best if I improve the answer :) I will eventually do it myself later anyways, but I have a deadline in a Java project in a couple hours, so have to do that first.